# Creating .deb packages from prebuilt binaries?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging

I would like to create a Debian/Ubuntu .deb package from a set of prebuilt binaries. I don't have any access to the source code. The only tutorials I've found on creating debs require source code access, and so do all the convenient and easy tools for creating Debian packages.

So how can I create a deb from a folder of binaries?

Answer (score 6):

1) you need to know where to put those binaries: in /usr/bin?

2) Then, you need you create yourself a temp directory for packaging e.g. /tmp/package

3) You need to write yourself DEBIAN control files e.g. control, postrm, preinst etc.

4) You put those DEBIAN control files in /tmp/package/DEBIAN

5) You run 'dpkg-deb'

This is just a quick overview; some steps are missing.  Have a look at how I do this with my makefiles [here](http://code.google.com/p/epapi/) under /trunk/project.

This should get you started anyhow. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I've found [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) to be very useful for creating binary `.deb` packages.

Answer (score 1):

you should have a look [here](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/index.en.html) (part 4 and 6 for basic stuffs)

Answer (score 1):

See `man dpkg-deb` (`--build` command) and `man deb-control`.

`.deb` file creation with `DEBIAN` directory instead of `debian` one is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a remark, here is an example DEBIAN/control file

```
Package: <put package name here>
Version: 1.0
Section: base
Priority: optional
Architecture: amd64
Depends: <put dependency packages here>
Maintainer: Somebody Somename <s.somename@someaddress.com>
Description: Short description
  Long description, mind the spaces in front of this line
```